# Blocking USB through GPO in 2008 R2 & excluding certain users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I am looking for blocking USB devices in our Win 2008R2 SP1 server. I am already aware about GPO policy "\User Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Removable Storage Access" & it's working perfectly here.

Only there are few concern's as below.

1: I want to exclude certain users/groups from this policy.

2: All other rules/policy's in original "default domain controller policy"  should be applied to everyone like PW policies, WSUS policies etc..

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure your desired settings in a new GPO.
2. Create a Security group for the users that you DO want the policy to apply to.
3. Add the appropriate users to this Security group.
4. Configure Security Filtering on the new GPO to apply to this Security group only.
5. Link the OU to the location where the user objects are (either at the Domain level or at the OU level if you have your users in an OU).

Comment: How to link the OU. i.e. 5th step??

Comment: in GPMC right click the location you want to link the GPO to and select "Link an Existing GPO" from the context menu and then select your GPO in the "Select GPO" window and click OK.

Comment: Not working. I have linked both the GPO's. Default Domain policy & custom policy called USB_Deny. Still Users added into SG called USB_Block able to access it.

Comment: Still I am struggling with GPO. 

Below things I did so far.

1. Created new OU called Laptop-Users & then new group called USb_Block. Added several users into it.

2. Created new GPO called USb_Deny_Gpo & added certain rules/policies to block the USB storage devices.

3. Then Right clicked on domain xyz.com to link default domain policy & Usb_deny_Gpo.

4. Added Usb_Block group into Security Filter of scope tab in Usb_Deny_Gpo with read & apply group policy permission.

This settings seems OK for me. But, still users in my network able to access USB drives.

Comment: Anyone please...

Comment: So this policy has been applied and works for you but no one else?  Have you performed a gpresult under their account ("gpresult /h gpreport.html") to see if the policy shows as a applied GPO or if its evening showing?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the easiest way to exclude users is to utilize the advanced button on the delegation tab of the group policy object. Add the user/group you want to exclude, and check the box to deny them all rights to the policy. Since deny statements take precedence over allow, this will work to exclude certain users/groups even if they are a member of a group (such as "Authenticated Users") that has rights to the GPO